# How to use edge addon proxy as the system proxy

Tags: windows-10

I have an edge addon named setupVPN and I can use it as proxy while I surf with Edge().
Now I have some GUI applications, for example, github desktop. How can I use the proxy provided by the edge addon setupVPN in GUI applications?

Answer (score 0):

You can only use an Edge Application within Microsoft Edge. If you want to use the proxy or VPN connection for other programs, you'll have to download an vpn application with also provides an desktop application.

Browser addons will mostly not work with other programs installed on your computer because of technical limitations and security reasons.